# How do I bring a TYPO3 constant into ext_localconf.php?

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

In my TYPO3 site package I have set a custom RTE preset by adding this line to `ext_localconf.php` :

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['my_preset'] = 'EXT:my_site/Configuration/RTE/custom.yaml';
```

Is there a way I can allow the yaml file location to be overridden by a constant?

Comment: Modification to `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']` can be done via `AdditionalConfiguration.php` but I'm not sure if paths outside of an ext-folder can be used. *Why* do you want to override the settings which you have specially set for this website/customer before?

Comment: @JulianHofmann I want to be able to use this site package as a base across multiple sites. Then override with templates etc. from fileadmin where needed. Can I perhaps use a variable from typoscript setup as the path?

Comment: Each website should have a sitepackage even if it is "only" extending another base-sitepackage. Templates and configuration stuff should *not* be in the fileadmin. 
You can include the yaml of the base-sitepackage in the yaml of your sitepacke and then override single settings.

Comment: @JulianHofmann Unfortunately the setup I have to work with means adding/updating extensions is a big pain and bottlenecks the whole process. Plus it seems a bit over the top to make a whole extension just to, for example, add a link class to the rte.

Comment: If you want to have the sitepackage "as a base across multiple sites", how are you planning to integrate all the other differences between the websites??? Exactly for all this, having sitepackages is good practice.

Comment: @JulianHofmann I've set it up to be adjustable with constants, not for all websites ever, but for a range that are similar. It is just the RTE that is the problem and I don't want to have to make a whole sitepackage for one added classname.